# Completing a Graph in Grouped Steps

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

OK, so I want to write some software to solve this problem:

There is a networking event where business owners get to talk to other business owners at a table for some set amount of time. There are n people attending the event, the number of people who may sit at one table is s, and there are t tables.

After the allotted time has passed, all of the people shuffle in some way so that they are able to talk to new people. The idea is to give everyone attending the event a chance to talk to everyone else (A complete graph) with as few redundant connections as possible.

It's not a requirement that the graph be 100% complete, but as close as possible would be nice.

To summarize the variables (with realistic values):

```
    n - the number of people attending the event (20-40)
    s - the number of people who can sit at one table(5-8)
    t - the number of tables (4-10)
    c - the number of shuffles (what ever is required for the setup)
```

So I don't really have any experience with graph theory, but this my rough idea to solve the problem:

1. Form a list of all possible connections, there are (n* (n-1))/2 of them
2. Build a table adding 1 unmade connection at a time, until the table has the right number of people
3. try to add connections that don't create redundant connections
4. Don't add a connection to a table if it will result in a person sitting at more than 1 table.
5. Repeat this until all connections have been used.

I'm having a lot of trouble thinking about how this will work/ implementing it. I was hoping somebody might be able to give me some advice or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds almost like some variation of a [split graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_graph) problem or a [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) problem.

It's a relatively complicated problem, and the fact that you don't require an exact solution makes it difficult to tell what you really need to do to get an "acceptably good" solution.  I would advise reading those two pages to start with, in the hope that you might find something that is a match to your current situation.

I agree that working backwards from a complete graph might be the best strategy.  You start with the complete graph, and then attempt to partition it into components such that you get your arrangement.  Your proposed algorithm might well work.  It's probably best to just try it and see, and ask another question if it doesn't work :)